# Re-sample train data so it represents real-world data

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, classification, sampling

I have a classification problem - will a student pass a course, or not.

- I have real-world data consisting of million of students enrolling in my course.
- In addition, I have 1,000 tagged students - train data -
  with a target value of "passes the course" or "doesn't pass the
  course".
- Each student has few features - such as average math grades,
  number of years studying, etc. I have a total of 8 features.

My **1,000 tagged students don't represent the million real-world students** I have and need to predict for. For example, the 1,000 tagged students have higher average math grades and more years of studying. So if I train my model on the 1,000 tagged students, it will have bad results.

How can I **select X tagged students from my tagged 1,000** so the **X students will represent the million real-world students**, with respect for all of the 8 features?

My idea: I can re-sample the 1,000 tagged students based on 1 feature. But I that results in a different distribution for the other features, and I can't find a mechanism to keep the distribution of the train data and all real-world data the same for the 8 features.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may sound pedantic, but it's not:  How do you know your 1,000 students aren't representative of the general population?

Comment: @NaiveBayesian, because they were selected manually. Merely an assumption

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is survey weighting.
https://www.pewresearch.org/methods/2018/01/26/how-different-weighting-methods-work/

The most common approach is raking. Roughly speaking you add a weight to each of your training data, and fix the proportion for one feature, and then go on to the next iteratively until all your features have a matching (weighted) proportion in the training data as in your real world data

in addition, by taking eg pairs of features as one variable you can ensure that the joint distribution of that pair of features is matched

see eg anesrake R package

Comment: Do you have any python packages related to the subject?

Comment: can't recommend any, but here is one: https://pypi.org/project/ipfn/

Comment: @Dave I don't have a package specific to this exact scenario, however [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) has a lot of tools for per-sample and per-class weighting. Combined with [numpy](https://numpy.org/) and [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) you will have all the tools needed to analyse the distributions and compute weight/sampling logic. Additionally, there is a popular scikit-learn extension library called [imbalanced-learn](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/) with extra tools for handling imbalanced class and sample distributions.